# Только три процента всей воды на Земле явля(Е/Ю)тся пресной

Tags: грамматика

> Только три процента всей воды на Земле явля(Е/Ю)тся пресной

What letter should I choose there? Е or Ю?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case the following rule would apply (Rosenthal et al., №184.2):

> Форма единственного числа сказуемого указывает на совокупность предметов, форма множественного числа – на отдельные предметы. Ср.: *В городе строится пять объектов соцкультбыта* (единое нерасчлененное представление о действии). – *В крупнейших городах страны строятся еще пять объектов соцкультбыта* (расчлененное представление о действии).

Since we do not refer each percent separately, we should use the singular form.

Comment: WOW!!! Thank you!

Answer (score -4):

три процента ... являются, так как "являться" - глагол относится к 1 спряжению. http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_91